# call event when scale value changed

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm working on UI page to represent the scale's weight value. 
c# code constantly read the scale value from real scale device 
and I have to show value to the UI(wpf) screen.

When scale value changed UI screen(scaleShow.xaml.cs) need to know the 
scale value has been changed.

so I'm thinking about to use the event to let scaleShow.xaml.cs page know. 
but not sure how to implement it

```
MainWindow.xaml.cs
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate()
    {
        this.ctTbWeight.Text = this.curWeight + " kg";
        //when this.curWeight value changed I want to the scale.xaml.cs page notice it 
    }




scale.xaml.cs
     public scale(EventHandler handler, ILog logger, ObservableDictionary<string, LanguageChangedImpl> language, Stopwatch elapse)
            {
                InitializeComponent();


                this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(_PageLoaded);

                this.tel = new Telegram();
                this.tel.Name = this.GetType().Name;
                this.pagingMachine = handler;
                this.def = new Defines();
                this.log = logger;
                this.lang = language;
                this.elapseTime = elapse;
            }
```

I try to create the event in MainWindow.cs but not sure how to use it(if its button click it's kind of obvious to use)

```
public event EventHandler getWeight;
        protected virtual void OngetWeight(EventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = getWeight;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
```

please give me some direction to let scale page notice the scale value been changed. if you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using events, you could use a Dependency property and a Binding on your display control.
In the code behind, create a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleValue", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(double)));

public double ScaleValue { get { return (double) GetValue(ScaleValueProperty); } set { SetValue(ScaleValueProperty, value); } }
```

NB: I have assumed a double for the value - change this if yours is something else.
In the xaml file for the UI, just bind the appropriate property to the ScaleValue

```
Text = {Binding ScaleValue}
```

The normal dependency property notification events should handle updates to the UI when ScaleValue changes

Comment: is it possible to use event in this situation?>

Comment: Certainly. See following answer

Answer (score 0):

Using an event handler:

public event EventHandler myEvent;

```
public MainWindow()
{
 InitializeComponent();
 myEvent = OnMyEvent;
}

private void OnMyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //do UI updates
}
```

Now in the loop where you check the scale value, trigger the event by calling

```
myEvent?.Invoke(this,null)
```

Comment: Actually, a more OOP way would be to create a ScaleMeasure object that handles the reading of the value. It would have an event such as OnScaleValueChange.
The MainWindow would subscribe to this event and use that to trigger UI updates.